# How to get rid of single quotes in mongodb strings in jade template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug, traversal

I load text from mongodb (mongoose) and display it in my jade templates (ExpressJS app). `console` output from mongo is fine and as expected. But when parsed in jade template all text is surrounded with single quotes. If I use json file as data source instead it doesn't happen.

My Mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Profile = mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    summary: { da: String, en: String }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', Profile, 'profile');
```

My json looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57e2685369e4bc0a8ca6c64d"),
  "name" : "Ole Frank Jensen",
  "imageUrl" : "https:someurl.jpg",
  "summary" : { "da" : "asdf", "en" : "123" }
}
```

I use this method to filter for chosen language. It uses npm package https://github.com/substack/js-traverse to traverse each node in mongo results:

```
var filterLanguage = function(language, obj) {
    return traverse(obj).map(function (item) {
        if (this.key === language) {
            this.parent.update(item);
        }
    });
};
```

- In my jade template I output strings like this: 
  `p= profile.name`
- Output looks like this:
  `<p>'Ole Frank Jensen'</p>`
- Expected output: 
  `<p>Ole Frank Jensen</p>`

Why are the quotes there and what's the best way to get rid of them in the view?